# How to pass values from HTML webresource to javascript on window close MSCRM

Tags: javascript, html, dynamics-crm, customization

I am opening HTML webresource using `Xrm.Navigation.openWebResource` but on closing of HTML window I want to pass values from HTML to javascript file from where it is opened. Is there call back function can be implemented?

If I open HTML window using `window.open` I can call parent javascript function using `window.opener.functionname` on close but click but I want to know how I can pass values to parent javascript file on close button click of HTML window.

I tried with `window.parent.opener.Functionname()` but it is not working - getting `functionname is undefined` but it is defined in parent javascript. Pls suggest.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the 'old' (as it not the unified interface) user interface with turboforms enabled then the parents javascript is actually in a extra iframe called customScriptFrame, and not on the parent itself.

To call something on the parent you can use

```
parent.customScriptsFrame.functionname() for IE
```

and

```
parent.customScriptsFrame.contentWindow.functionname() on chrome.
```

On the unified interface its much the same, but far more troublesome. 
Now the scripts are in a iframe called ClientApiFrame_[n] where [n] is some random number. And i haven't found a good way to determin that number ahead of time from a webresource.
You could go over all frames of the parent in javascript (parent.frames) to find one that has a id that starts with ClientApiFrame_ but that will throw errors trying to read frames with sources set to external domains, and i dont think is very good practice.

Another possibility is registering the function you want to call with the parent ahead of time. so in the main javascript use this.

```
parent.functionname = functionname
```

And then from the webResource you can use the normal

```
parent.functionname
```

Comment: Is this supported?

Answer (score 0):

If the webresource is embedded in the form, then use `window.parent`

If you `Xrm.Navigation.openWebResource` to open it, then use `window.opener`